# Load WooCommerce templates from my plugin folder first

Tags: plugin-development, plugins

I try to write a plugin for WooCommerce (https://github.com/bassjobsen/woocommerce-twitterbootstrap). I want my templates load like this:

1. my custom theme / template path / template name
2. my custom theme / template
3. **my plugin / template name**
4. woocommerce / template name

So when the template not exists in the theme folder it is load from my plugin folder (if exists) instead of the Woocommece folder. On http://www.skyverge.com/blog/override-woocommerce-template-file-within-a-plugin/ if found a working solution for templates load by `woocommerce_get_template`. But this will not work for `woocommerce_get_template_part` cause this function call `locate_template` instead of `woocommerce_locate_template` (is this a bug?).

Question: I want to know how to overwrite / manipulate `locate_template()` so it try to load the files from my plugin folder first. Or any other solution to do this.

**update** thanks to @jesper i cloud load templates now:

```
function 

my_template_redirect(){
   //pages you want to make true, ex. is_shop()
   global $woocommerce;
   if(is_shop()) {

       $plugin_dir = WP_PLUGIN_DIR.'/'.str_replace( basename( __FILE__), "", plugin_basename(__FILE__) );

    var_dump($plugin_dir);

    load_template($plugin_dir . '/templates/archive-product.php');
   }
}

add_action('template_redirect','my_template_redirect');
```

<strike>`/templates/archive-product.php` includes `content-product.php` from the same plugin template dir. `content-product.php` makes use of the `global $product` which is null in this case. Do i need to load a other function to set `$product`?</strike>

The above also gives my an other error:
PHP Warning:  call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'woocommerce_before_main_content_grid' not found or invalid function name in /home/bass/Dropbox/testomgeving/jamedotheme/wordpress/wp-includes/plugin.php

With the above code i could write a function to conditional include files in templates/archive-product.php (**so solved!**)

Comment: At this time `locate_template` has no filter nor action hooks and is not a pluggable function: you cannot overwrite / manipulate it without change the core file [wp-includes/template.php](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.6/wp-includes/template.php#L368).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use [template redirect](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect) action.

I don't test it but it should work:

```
function my_template_redirect(){
   //pages you want to make true, ex. is_shop()
   if(is_shop()) {
       $plugin_dir = WP_PLUGIN_DIR.'/'.str_replace( basename( __FILE__), "", plugin_basename(__FILE__) );
    load_template($plugin_dir . 'your-template.php');
   }
}

add_action('template_redirect','my_template_redirect');
```

Comment: thanks. This does not seems to set $name. $name will be always empty.

Comment: I copied from a plugin I coded, check it now, change de variable to the name of your template.

Comment: Thanks. It will work some way. If will have to check if i need some conditional use of this action. Now i found the template twice (one on the right place and one on the end of the source).

Comment: hi @jesper thanks. Yes i can load templates now, but the product var needed for the loop is not set, see update of my question