# WooCommerce - Load Templates From Plugin For All Template Files

Tags: plugins, templates, woocommerce-offtopic

I've read a bunch of articles about [overriding the default /woocommerce/ templates](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/) and tried implementing the following (which were the best/most relevant that I could find all to no avail):

- [Load WooCommerce templates from my plugin folder first](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/110602/load-woocommerce-templates-from-my-plugin-folder-first)
- [Override WooCommerce Template File Within a Plugin](https://www.skyverge.com/blog/override-woocommerce-template-file-within-a-plugin/)

Essentially, what I would like to accomplish is: load all template files (for archives and posts not just template parts) from ~/wp-content/my-plugin/templates/woocommerce/*  UNLESS the files are in my theme (and I don't have to override each file instance in my function) . For instance:

- `~/wp-content/my-plugin/templates/woocommerce/single-product.php` *(this seems like it just doesn't want to load via plugin)*
- `~/wp-content/my-plugin/templates/woocommerce/archive-products.php` *(this seems like it just doesn't want to load via plugin)*
- `~/wp-content/my-plugin/templates/woocommerce-pdf-invoices-packing-slips/*` *(I also want to be able to **override other plugin extension templates** just like I would be able to in my child theme)*

**EDIT:**

The friendly folks at [SkyVerge](https://www.skyverge.com/blog/override-woocommerce-template-file-within-a-plugin/) sent me the following code, which I tested and confirm that it works for template *parts*.

```
// Locate the template in a plugin
function myplugin_woocommerce_locate_template( $template, $template_name, $template_path ) {

    $_template = $template;

    if ( ! $template_path ) {
        $template_path = WC()->template_path();
    }

    $plugin_path = myplugin_plugin_path() . '/templates/';

    // Look within passed path within the theme - this is priority
    $template = locate_template(
        array(
            trailingslashit( $template_path ) . $template_name,
            $template_name
        )
    );

    // Modification: Get the template from this plugin, if it exists
    if ( ! $template && file_exists( $plugin_path . $template_name ) ) {
        $template = $plugin_path . $template_name;
    }

    // Use default template
    if ( ! $template ) {
        $template = $_template;
    }

    return $template;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_locate_template', 'myplugin_woocommerce_locate_template', 10, 3 );

// Helper to get the plugin's path on the server
function myplugin_plugin_path() {
    // gets the absolute path to this plugin directory
    return untrailingslashit( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) );
}
```

The above code works for something like:

- `~/myplugin/templates/single-product/product-image.php`

But does NOT work for:

- `~/myplugin/templates/single-product.php`

Where I'm getting stuck:

- There are solutions to override bits and pieces of WC templates, but there I've not found / been able to create a solution that does *comprehensive* overrides (i.e. overriding ability just like a child theme would)
- I can't seem to find the right combination of filter hooks; single-product.php and archive-product.php seem to be controlled by functions outside the standard WC template functions

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

WooCommerce uses the `template_include` filter/hook to load main templates like `archive-product.php` and `single-product.php`. And [here's](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Template_Loader.html) the class which handles main templates.

And there's a filter in that class which you can use to capture the default file (name) which WooCommerce loads based on the current request/page — e.g. `single-product.php` for single product pages.

You can't, however, simply hook to that filter, return a custom template path and expect it to be used (because the path has to be relative to the active theme folder). But you can do something like in the second snippet below (which is tried & tested working on WordPress 5.2.2 with WooCommerce 3.6.5, the latest version as of writing):

1. First, a helper function:

   ```php
   // Helper function to load a WooCommerce template or template part file from the
   // active theme or a plugin folder.
   function my_load_wc_template_file( $template_name ) {
       // Check theme folder first - e.g. wp-content/themes/my-theme/woocommerce.
       $file = get_stylesheet_directory() . '/woocommerce/' . $template_name;
       if ( @file_exists( $file ) ) {
           return $file;
       }

       // Now check plugin folder - e.g. wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/woocommerce.
       $file = 'full/path/to/your/plugin/' . 'woocommerce/' . $template_name;
       if ( @file_exists( $file ) ) {
           return $file;
       }
   }
   ```
2. To override main WooCommerce templates (e.g. `single-product.php`):

   ```php
   add_filter( 'woocommerce_template_loader_files', function( $templates, $template_name ){
       // Capture/cache the $template_name which is a file name like single-product.php
       wp_cache_set( 'my_wc_main_template', $template_name ); // cache the template name
       return $templates;
   }, 10, 2 );

   add_filter( 'template_include', function( $template ){
       if ( $template_name = wp_cache_get( 'my_wc_main_template' ) ) {
           wp_cache_delete( 'my_wc_main_template' ); // delete the cache
           if ( $file = my_load_wc_template_file( $template_name ) ) {
               return $file;
           }
       }
       return $template;
   }, 11 );
   ```
3. To override WooCommerce template parts (retrieved using `wc_get_template_part()`):

   ```php
   add_filter( 'wc_get_template_part', function( $template, $slug, $name ){
       $file = my_load_wc_template_file( "{$slug}-{$name}.php" );
       return $file ? $file : $template;
   }, 10, 3 );
   ```
4. To override other WooCommerce templates (retrieved using `wc_get_template()` or `wc_locate_template()`):

   ```php
   add_filter( 'woocommerce_locate_template', function( $template, $template_name ){
       $file = my_load_wc_template_file( $template_name );
       return $file ? $file : $template;
   }, 10, 2 );
   ```

Btw, there's also the `woocommerce_template_path` filter for those of you who're just looking to change the default WooCommerce templates folder (`woocommerce`) *in the active theme folder*.

Comment: Thank You, Works Perfectly

Answer (score 2):

```
function woo_template_replace( $located, $template_name, $args, $template_path, $default_path ) {

if( file_exists( plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'templates/' . $template_name ) ) {
    $located = plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'templates/' . $template_name;
}

return $located;
}


function woo_get_template_part( $template , $slug , $name ) {

if( empty( $name ) ) {
    if( file_exists( plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . "/templates/{$slug}.php" ) ) {
        $template = plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . "/templates/{$slug}.php";
    }
} else {
    if( file_exists( plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . "/templates/{$slug}-{$name}.php" ) ) {
        $template = plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . "/templates/{$slug}-{$name}.php";
    }
return $template;
}

add_filter( 'wc_get_template' , 'woo_template_replace' , 10 , 5 );

add_filter( 'wc_get_template_part' , 'woo_get_template_part' , 10 , 3 );
```

You can use this snippet in your plugin root file and place your all woocommerce templates file in templates directory.

Plugin structure for reference

```
plugins
  woo-template-replace (plugin root folder)
     woo-template-replace.php (plugin root file)
     templates (folder)
        single-content.php (woocommerce template file)
        searchform.php (woocommerce template file)
```

Comment: Thanks, Syed!

Your code does work for some parts of what I want. For instance, using ~/my-plugin/templates/single-product/product-image.php does work, for instance. However, ~/my-plugin/templates/single-product.php does not work (I'm guessing that this would have to be hooked into single_template or something else). I've updated my post a bit to reflect newer information.

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario you can use the following filter wc_get_template_part.

Hook reference link: 
[wc_get_template_part](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-wc_get_template_part.html#142-175)

If you don't know how to use filters read this article [wordpress hooks for non developers](http://docs.presscustomizr.com/article/26-wordpress-actions-filters-and-hooks-a-guide-for-non-developers)

Comment: Hi Syed,

Thanks for your reply. I am familiar with hooks and edited my post to include code that I tried using `wc_get_template_part` ...which did not work

Comment: I think you missed something?? Can you post your code? This is only one hook resolve your problem.

Comment: Hi Syed. Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, I'm not quite sure what you mean. Again, I want my plugin to load ALL woocommerce files from ~/my-plugin/templates/woocommerce

Answer (score -1):

If you want to overriding the templates for WooCommerce, then I have your answer.
I just have created a complate WooCommerce Theme to my client and Support Everthing in WooCommerce so let's get started.

First of all before doing anything this page is very good if you read it slowly [WooCommerce Overriding the plugins templates](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/).

Step 1:
In the functions.php add the WooCommerce Support

```
if (!function_exists( 'albadrbakelser_setup')) :
    function albadrbakelser_setup() {

        // Add Woocommerce Support
        add_theme_support(
            'woocommerce', array(
                //'thumbnail_image_width' => 150,
                // 'gallery_thumbnail_image_width' => 100,
                //'single_image_width'    => 300,

                'product_grid'          => array(
                    'default_rows'    => 5,
                    'min_rows'        => 1,
                    'max_rows'        => 10,
                    'default_columns' => 4,
                    'min_columns'     => 1,
                    'max_columns'     => 4,
                    ),
                )
        );
        add_theme_support( 'wc-product-gallery-zoom' );
        add_theme_support( 'wc-product-gallery-lightbox' );
        add_theme_support( 'wc-product-gallery-slider' );


    }
endif;
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'albadrbakelser_setup' );
```

OR you can use just this if you don't want everythings

```
function mytheme_add_woocommerce_support() {
    add_theme_support( 'woocommerce' );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'mytheme_add_woocommerce_support' );
```

Step 2:
Override something.

Example: To add "Hello" to the single product title
copy: `wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/single-product/title.php` **to** `wp-content/themes/yourtheme/woocommerce/single-product/title.php`

Then Open the title.php that you have copied in this direction `wp-content/themes/yourtheme/woocommerce/single-product/title.php` and write Hello between the `h1 html tag` like this `<h1>Hello</h1>`. Then save the file

Last Step:
Go to the single product in your site to check if the Hello is there.
Make sure you have created a product to visit.

**Results**:

[image: Results]

**Note**:

In case nothings work try to create woocommerce.php file in your root by following this page https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/third-party-custom-theme-compatibility/

This is the page to start with
the add support https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/Declaring-WooCommerce-support-in-themes

Comment: Hello, Thanks for answering. But this not case here. the question is how to override woocommerce template inside a plugin?

Comment: Sorry for misunderstood. Should I delete my answer?